# How to use UpdateLayerStatistics() and GeodesicLength() in Python 3 sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyspatialite

Support for pyspatialite appears to have been overlooked for Python 3.x. The erstwhile replacement, sqlite3, is missing some critical functions such as UpdateLayerStatistics() and GeodesicLength().

The answer offered by @heibert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212189/cant-install-pyspatialite-with-python3-and-sqlite3) affirms that the installation package has not been updated for Python 3. That response is more than 4 years old, implying that support is not likely forthcoming.

There is a replacement package, sqlite3, but the queries with the aforementioned functions throw errors with that package imported.

- What is the appropriate solution to install pyspatialite in Python 3? or
- What are their renamed counterparts in sqlite3 (if they exist at all)? or
- What is the proper package to access those and other functions previously available in pyspatialite?

Answer (score 0):

The best response I found was [by sandro here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/o0jUwMUqx_g) which explains both why pyspatialite is obsolete and what to do to overcome the issue.